# How do I corrupt the master node on a UBI device?

Tags: linux, ubifs

I have an nand flash that appears as mtd and is attached to UBI and has 2 volumes and I want to know how to corrupt the master node in the UBI device.

Is it possible? The documentation says the master nodes are on LEBS 1 and 2 but I dont know how to directly corrupt those, I know how to corrupt volumes using ubiupdatevol i.e:

```
 ubiupdatevol /dev/ubi1_0 /dev/urandom -s 10000
```

but not how to do this.

Edit: it could be related to programming because I have seen some user space code snippets that does just this so maybe someone could post an example?

Theres also a kernel api call which I don't know how to use that atomically modifies LEBS on a ubi device.

Comment: This question is blatanly off-topic for SO as it is [not about programming](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If you edit your question to make it clear that you are trying to do this in a program, then it could be on-topic.  Specify which programming language or languages.

Comment: In C? how else would you do low level nand flash stuff really?